# Detect if hovering over image in div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an example:

```
<div class="class1" id="id_1">
test
</div>
```

```
function handler(ev) {
    let target = $(ev.target);
    let elId = target.attr('id');
    if( target.is("div[id^='id_']") ) {
         let lastChar = elId.substr(elId.length - 1);
       alert('The mouse was over'+ lastChar );
    }
}
$("div[id^='id_']").mouseleave(handler);
```

It works in such a way that if I hovering on an element, then alert is displayed - the problem occurs if I have only a picture in this `div` - then it does not work. How to make it work even more if I only have a picture like this, e.g. I have:

```
<div class="class1" id="id_1">
<img src="/img_src">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(ev.currentTarget)` or `$(this)` to reference the element that matches the selector rather than any target that is a descendant

```js
function handler(ev) {
   
    console.clear();   
    let $div = $(ev.currentTarget);
    let elId = $div.attr('id');
    console.log('currentTarget id:', elId)
    
    $div= $(this);
    elId =$div.attr('id');
    console.log('this id:', elId)
}
$("div[id^='id_']").mouseleave(handler);
```

```css
.class1{ margin : 1em; border: 1px solid green
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1" id="id_1">
<div class="inner">test 1</div>
</div>
<div class="class1" id="id_2">
<div class="inner">test 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that example works very well - and how can I additionally configure it for the `setInterval`?

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/g9eqy2n6/ - how can I configure it to work identically? Where can I look for some information about it?

Comment: Not at all clear what you want to accomplish using setInterval. The currentTarget is a property of an event object only also